# Performing moments.insert when using GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch for authentication

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to insert a "Moment" into a user's Google+ account, using the [google-api-objectivec-client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/). I think have the authentication process working properly. It's primarily the same way I have YouTube authentication set up, but with the correct scope and keychain name. However, when I try to run the query to insert the moment I get the following error:

> Error Domain=com.google.GTLJSONRPCErrorDomain Code=401 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Unauthorized)"

After looking at Google's documentation more carefully ([here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert#examples)) I found the following comment:

> When authenticating for moments.insert, you must include the `data-requestvisibleactions`
>   parameter to specify which types of App Activities your application will write.

Google has several examples of how to do this with other programming languages, but they don't have any examples for the objective-c library, and the objective-c project doesn't contain any examples of how to do this either.

I know that there's another authentication method, using the GPPSignIn button, which has a way to set the actions. However, my application is using multiple other Google API clients (YouTube, YouTube Analytics, and URL Shortener). Mixing the `GoogleOpenSource.framework` with the other Objective-C libraries causes a conflict. So, I need to use the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch class.

**My Authentication Code**

```
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController =
    [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin
                                             clientID:kGoogleApiClientId
                                         clientSecret:kGoogleApiClientSecret
                                     keychainItemName:kGooglePlusKeychainName
                                    completionHandler:^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {

              if (error)
                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
              else
                  app.googlePlusService.authorizer = auth; //this sets a property of my app delegate, to be used elsewhere in the application


    }];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

**The code I'm using to insert the "Moment"**

```
NSString *shareUrl = "http://www.google.com"; //just for this example

GTLPlusMoment *moment = [[GTLPlusMoment alloc] init];
moment.type = @"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

GTLPlusItemScope *target = [[GTLPlusItemScope alloc] init];
target.url = shareUrl;
moment.target = target;

GTLQueryPlus *query =
[GTLQueryPlus queryForMomentsInsertWithObject:moment
                                       userId:@"me"
                                   collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVault];

[app.googlePlusService executeQuery:query
                  completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                      id object,
                                      NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Got bad response from plus.moments.insert: %@", error);                     
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Moment inserted: %@",moment.identifier);
     }
 }];
```

Has anyone out there successfully found the place to add the `data-requestvisibleactions` parameter to either the authentication call or queryForMomentsInsertWithObject method to allow them to execute the `moments.insert` action without receiving an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add `data-requestvisibleactions` using Java Script code in `Authentication`. Once you `authorized` with `java script`, it will be authorized for all types of insert moments. There is no method in Objective c for adding `data-requestvisibleactions` in your code. Only the option is possible through Java Script.

For More derails Refer [THIS](http://www.googleplusdaily.com/2013/03/add-google-sign-in-in-6-easy-steps.html)

Comment: Thanks for you response. Unfortunately I'm still looking to see if anyone has found a workaround for this using the objective-c API client. Since I'm already using this library to authenticate YouTube I can't use the GoogleOpenSource.framework to implement the GPPSignin control, which does provide support for the requestvisibleactions value.

Comment: @BrianShamblen did u get solution for ur problem